# Fastlane match with multiple apps / certificates

Tags: android, ios, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, fastlane

We have two applications under the same apple developer account and fastlane is utilised to build both of these applications.

Both apps have their own separate repo and both have separate repos to hold their profiles and certs.

[image]

When fastlane generates new certs and profiles for each app, it generates an identical certificate for both applications and adds them to the keychain. So say we have **cert expire 14/01/22** for app 1 and **cert expire 10/01/2022** for app 2. Both have the same certificate name. This seems to cause Xcode to get confused and not pick up on the correct certificate for one of the projects, resulting in one of the projects working flawlessly and the other project giving this error as it isn't picking up the correct certificate due to having the same name.

[image]

Is there any way to change the name of the certificate that fastlane generates to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 3):

After some research and questioning, the solution is to have 1 repo that stores the profiles and cert to be shared with the multiple apps.

One repo will contain 1 cert and multiple profiles (depending on how many apps you have). So if you have two apps and are only worried about distribution. You will have 1 cert and 2 **match AppStore** profiles. One for each app.

As long as your Matchfile in each project points at the shared certificate repo.